# Ruby 1.8.6 LocalJumpError when dealing with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following code:

```
Tag.find_all_by_company_id(4).each.collect{|tag| tag.name }.join(",")
```

(Essentially I'm trying to build a JS array of tag names)

When I run this code, I get:

```
LocalJumpError: no block given
    from (irb):13:in `each'
    from (irb):13
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need the `each`. You could just replace it with:

```
Tag.find_all_by_company_id(4).collect{|tag| tag.name }.join(",")
```

The thing is, in Ruby 1.8.6, `each` expects a block. It won't return an enumerator.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, but the code can be made even shorter:

    Tag.find_all_by_company_id(4).collect(&:name).to_json